# Rewrite pages from a subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following setup:

```
index.php
config.php
   pages/
     index.php
     about.php
     contact.php
```

And when i want to visit "about.php", I need to visit http://host.com/index.php?page=about

Now I want to rewrite the URL so it looks like this: http://host.com/about.php

How should the .htaccess look? I'm a complete noob in mod_rewrite.

Comment: I tried things like "RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)\.php$ ?page=$1 [L]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
#External redirect with THE_REQUEST trick; change R to R=301 when everything works correctly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?page=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2.php\? [R=302,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If you visit `http://example.com/index.php?page=about` it will redirect you to `http://example.com/about.php`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But now the ErrorDocument 404 doesn't work anymore. When I visit a non-existent page that ends with .php I get a white site. When the non-existent page doesn't end with .php everything works fine.

Comment: Is there many pages that need to be redirected using the above code?

Comment: What you might need to do then is in the `index.php` file, check there if the redirect file exists. If it doesn't use something like `header('Location: http://example.com/linktoerrordocument');`